# Using xpath gives empty output

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I want to get address but they provide me empty what I am doing wrong in the XPath..... these is the page link https://www.findtruckservice.com/page/cummins-sales-and-service-farmington-nm-430653

Snapshot of the address:

[image]

Code trials:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from scrapy.http import Request


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    
    
    def start_requests(self):
            yield SeleniumRequest(
                url ="https://www.findtruckservice.com/search/?city=Florida%2C+CO&mainCat=1&subCat=Truck+Repair&lat=37.0731&lon=-106.247&cat_field=Mobile+Repair+-+Truck+Repair",
                wait_time = 3,
                screenshot = True,
                callback = self.parse,
                dont_filter = True
                )
    
    def parse(self, response):
            books = response.xpath("//h3//a//@href").extract()
            for book in books:
                url = response.urljoin(book)
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)
            
                    
    def parse_book(self, response):
            address=response.xpath("//div[1][@class='threecol align_left card']//div//text()").get()
            yield{
                'address':address
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
[...]

address = ' '.join([x.strip() for x in response.xpath("//div[@class='threecol align_left card'][1]/div[@class='container']/text()").extract()])
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the desired text from the [website](https://www.findtruckservice.com/page/cummins-sales-and-service-farmington-nm-430653) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.findtruckservice.com/page/cummins-sales-and-service-farmington-nm-430653")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[@class='sec-title' and text()='CONTACT']//following::div[@class='container']"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.findtruckservice.com/page/cummins-sales-and-service-farmington-nm-430653")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h4[@class='sec-title' and text()='CONTACT']//following::div[@class='container']"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Cummins Sales and Service
  1101 N Troy King Rd
  Farmington, NM
  505-327-7331 (primary)
  505-326-2948 (fax)
  ```

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)

Comment: thanks .... but I don't need phone number  .....

Comment: also they give me other detail of Hours,details.......I need only contact detail